# How to evaluate this limit of $x \to 3$ for $\frac{x+1}{x+2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to evaluate the limit of $\frac{x+1}{x+2}$ where $x \to 3$.

The answer is $0.8$ but I am getting $\frac{1}{2}$.

**My Steps:**

Replace $x$ with $3$.

$\frac{3+1}{3+2}$ = $\frac{4}{2}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$

I'm sure I'm missing something here, but I'm not sure what else  to do.

Comment: Observe that 3+2=5 not 2

Comment: You can plug in $x=3$ in the given term

Comment: Also, $\frac 42\ne \frac 12$.

Comment: $0.8$ = $\frac{4}{5}$

Comment: Sorry everyone, this was a really dumb mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x+1\over x+2$ is contuinuos at $x=3$ you can put $3$ in to formula and you'll get desired result.

And ${3+1\over 3+2} = {4\over 5} = 0.8$

Comment: Sorry, this was a dumb mistake on my part.